# Calling Func<string,object> in lambda

Tags: c#

I'm confused, why can't I call this as a function and how do I let myself call this as a function?

```
Error   1   'fn' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'
```

Source

```
Func<List<object>, List<object>, Func<string, object>> test;
test = (ls, fn) => fn(null);
```

Comment: What is the definiton of `fn`?

Comment: fn there has type List<object>

Comment: `fn` is a `List<object>`.  Your `test` returns a `Func<string,object>`

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Its suppose to recieve a `List<object>, Func<string object>` and return `List<object>`

Comment: You've got the Func backwards

Comment: @BruteCode Well, according to your definition it takes two lists of of objects and returns a function that takes a string and returns an object

Comment: @BruteCode Also note that just changing the order of the `func` definition wouldn't help.  Your outer function is apparently supposed to return a list, but the inner function returns an object, not a list, so it still wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm confused.

Yep. Let's unconfuse you.

> What's wrong with this?

```
Func<List<object>, List<object>, Func<string, object>> test;
test = (ls, fn) => fn(null);
```

This says that `test` is a function that takes two lists and returns a function from string to object. The lists are `ls` and `fn`. So the type of `fn` is `List<object>`, which is not something that can be invoked.

Perhaps you should describe what you're trying to do here, as it is not at all clear from the code.

> Its suppose to recieve a `List<object>`, `Func<string, object>` and return `List<object>`

I don't think that can be right, since you want to *invoke* that function and get a `List<object>` back, but a `Func<string, object>` returns an `object`.

Perhaps what you intended to write was

```
Func<List<object>, Func<string, List<object>>, List<object>> test;
test = (ls, fn) => fn(null);
```

Now the type of `ls` is `List<object>` and the type of `fn` is `Func<string, List<object>>`. So when `fn` is invoked, it will return a `List<object>` as is required by `test`.

Make sense?

Remember, in `Func<A, B, R>`, A and B are the parameter types and R is the return type.

Comment: Oh return value is the last param? Thats counter intuitive since C# always has return type before params

Comment: This still won't compile as `fn` returns an `object` and the delegate assumes the return type is `List<object>`.

Comment: @BruteCode Funny you say that, Eric has a blog post on the subject, if memory serves.

Comment: Oh right I loop the elements which I didnt add here but this is good enough

Comment: @Servy: I hope the answer isn't 'because function languages write it that way'

Comment: @Servy: Here is the blog post about [why the return type parameter is last](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/25/why-is-the-return-type-parameter-last.aspx).

Comment: @Virtlink Thanks, it was bugging me that I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the following

```
Func<List<object>, Func<string, List<object>>, List<object>> test;
```

or

```
Func<List<object>, Func<string, object>, object> test;
```

for this to work

```
test = (ls, fn) => fn(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<List<object>, List<object>, Func<string, object>> test = Test;

    }

    private static Func<string, object> Test(List<object> objects, List<object> list)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you want, but this compile and works:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Func<List<object>, List<object>, Func<string, object>> test = (a, b) => 
    {
        a = b;
        return AnotherMethod;
    };
}

public object AnotherMethod(string value)
{
    return (object)value;
}
```